# I don´t know what´s wrong with this function

Tags: sql, database, function

Hey... I have this database and I need to create a function that returns the percentage of students that passed a subject but I don´t know what I did wrong... Could you help me please??? Here is my diagram[image: Diagram] and here is my function...

```
create function fnPassedStudents(@Semester varchar(7),@CodSubjects varchar(5))
returns @Passed
TABLE (
Semester varchar(7),
Cod_Subjects varchar(5),
Name_Subjects varchar(80),
Nro_Students int,
Nro_Passed float,
Nro_Failed float,
PercentagePassed varchar(4))
as
begin
declare @NroPassed float
select @NroPassed = count(M.Cod_Student)
from Matricula M inner join Subjects A on M.Cod_Subjects = A.Cod_Subjects
Where M.Semester=@Semester and M.Cod_Subjects = @CodSubjects and M.Grade>=10

insert into @Passed 
select M.Semester, A.Cod_Subjects, A.Name_Subjects, COUNT(M.Cod_Student) as Total, 
@NroPassed as Passed, (COUNT(M.Cod_Student) - @NroPassed) as Failed,
((@NroPassed * 100)/(count(M.Cod_Student))) as PercentagePassed
from Matricula M inner join Subjects A on M.Cod_Subjects = A.Cod_Subjects
Group by M.Semester, A.Cod_Subjects, A.Name_Subjects
return  
end
go
```

I´m not sure if this information is enough... but please be patient and I´ll add anything you need... Thanks!!!

Comment: What is it doing or not doing?  Does it crash?  Give an error?  Or just not do what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create function fnPassedStudents(@Semester varchar(7),@CodSubjects varchar(5))
returns @Passed
TABLE (
Semester varchar(7),
Cod_Subjects varchar(5),
Name_Subjects varchar(80),
Nro_Students int,
Nro_Passed float,
Nro_Failed float,
PercentagePassed varchar(4))
as
begin
insert into @Passed 
select
    M.Semester,
    A.Cod_Subjects,
    A.Name_Subjects,
    count(distinct M.cod_student),
    count(case when M.Grade>=10 then 1 end),
    count(*) - count(case when M.Grade>=10 then 1 end),
    count(case when M.Grade>=10 then 1 end) / count(distinct M.cod_student) * 100
from Matricula M
inner join Subjects A on M.Cod_Subjects = A.Cod_Subjects
Group by M.Semester, A.Cod_Subjects, A.Name_Subjects
return  
end
go
```

Ingredients

- CASE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx
- DISTINCT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx

`count(distinct M.cod_student)` - number of students taking a semester/subject
`case when M.Grade>=10 then 1 end` - produces 1 when passed, null otherwise. NULLs are not COUNTed
`count(*) - count(case..)` - the complement of passed = failed